# ABAP Program to notify Users X amount of days before user account will be disabled

Tags: abap

I'm currently learning ABAP and trying to make an enhancement but have broken down in confusion on how to go about building on top of existing code. I have a program that runs periodically via a background job that disables user accounts X amount of days (in this case 90 days of inactive usage based on USR02~TRDAT).

I want to add an enhancement to notify the User via their email address (result of usr02~bname to match usr21~bname to pass the usr21~persnumber and usr21~addrnumber to adr6 which will point to the adr6~smtp_addr of the user, providing the usr02~bname -> adr6~smtp_addr relationship) based on their last logon date being 30, 15, 7, 5, 3, and 1 day away from the 90 day inactivity threshold with a link to the SAP system to help them reactivate the account with ease.

I'm beginning to think that an enhancement might not be a good idea but rather create a new program and schedule the background job daily. Any guidance or information would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Where are you trying to put the enhancement?

Answer (score 2):

Extract

```
CLASS cl_inactive_users_reader DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF ts_inactive_user,
        user_name          TYPE syst_uname,
        days_of_inactivity TYPE int1,
      END OF ts_inactive_user.
    TYPES tt_inactive_users TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_inactive_user WITH EMPTY KEY.
    CLASS-METHODS read_inactive_users
      IMPORTING
        min_days_of_inactivity TYPE int1
      RETURNING
        VALUE(result)          TYPE tt_inactive_users.
ENDCLASS.
```

Then refactor

```
REPORT block_inactive_users.

DATA(inactive_users) = cl_inactive_users_readers=>read_inactive_users( 90 ).
LOOP AT inactive_users INTO DATA(inactive_user).
  " block user
ENDLOOP.
```

And add

```
REPORT warn_inactive_users.

DATA(inactive_users) = cl_inactive_users_readers=>read_inactive_users( 60 ).
LOOP AT inactive_users INTO DATA(inactive_user).
  CASE inactive_user-days_of_inactivity.
    " choose urgency
  ENDCASE.
  " send e-mail
ENDLOOP.
```

and run both reports daily.

Don't create a big ball of mud by squeezing new features into existing code.

Comment: Hey Florian, 

I managed to get the user selection to work perfectly--or atleast as to how I'd like it to...

Unfortunately I'm struggling on the email part...https://pastebin.com/JfdCJCdb

I now have a table created IT_USERS that stores all the Users SAP IDs & email addresses (if maintained). I'm trying to grasp the concept now of being able to send them an email and verifying it via SOST...

Comment: There is a couple of classes that allow sending e-mails. `cl_sut_job_utilities=>send_emails` is the one I lately used. It's actually part of the ABAP unit test frame ("sut") and usually used to send out unit test results from nightly builds.

Answer (score 1):

From SAP [wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=189893877):

> The enhancement concept allows you to add your own functionality to SAP's standard business applications without having to modify the original applications. To modify the standard SAP behavior as per customer requirements, we can use enhancement framework.

As per your description, it doesn't sound like a use case for an enhancement. It isn't an intervention in an existing process. The original process and your new requirement are two different processes with some mutual logical part - selection of days of inactivity of users. The two shouldn't rely on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Structurally I think it is best to have a separate program for computing which e-mails need to be sent and when, and a separate program for actually sending them.

I would copy your original program to a new one, and modify it a little bit so that instead of disabling a user, it records into some table for each user: 1) an e-mail 2) a date when to send 3) how many days left (30, 15, 7, etc) 4) status if the e-mail was sent or not. Initially you can even have multiple such jobs for each period (30, 15, 7 etc) and pass it as a parameter (which you use inside instead of 90).

This program you run daily as a job and it populates that table with e-mail "tasks" of what needs to be sent today. It just adds new lines, so lines from yesterday should stay in there.

The 2nd program should just read that table and send actual e-mails and update the statuses. You run that program daily as well.

This way you have:

- overview: just check the table to see what's going on
- control: if the e-mailer dies or hangs, you can restart it and it will continue where it left off; with statuses you avoid sending duplicate mails
- you can make sure that you don't send outdated e-mails if in your mailer script you ignore all tasks older than say 2 days

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify your confusion about the use of enhancements:
You would want to use enhancements in terms of 'something' happens or is going to happen in the system and you would want to change this standard way.

That something, let's call it event or process could be for example an order is placed, a certain user is logging onto the system or a material has been or is going to be changed.

The change could be notifying another system of an order or checking the logged on user with additional checks for example his GUI version and warn him/her if not up-to-date.

Ask yourself, what process on the system does the execution of your program or code depend on. Does anything need to happen before the program is executed? No, only elapsing time.

Even if you had found an enhancement, you would want to use. If this process using the enhancement would not be run in 90 days, your mails would not be sent, because the enhancement would never been called.

**edit**: That being said, supposing you mean by enhancement 'building on your existing program' instead of 'creating a new one' would be absolutely not the right terminology for enhancement in the sap universe.

I would extend the functionality of your existing program, since you already compute how many days are left and you would have only one job to maintain.